Why RSA uses exponentiation instead of multiplication by the inverse of $e^{-1}$?
I better clarify my question. If the problem of RSA is finding the inverse of $e^{-1} = e$ in:
$a^e \mod N$
Why don't we just do:
$ae \mod N$
for encryption, and
$ae^{-1} \mod N$
for decryption?
Since I'm quite sure that the answer is: "because the former formula is attackable", it would be really helpful at least a resource to understand such attack.
Edit: I'm going to answer my own question, thanks to everyone has answered, I apologize if I was a little bit rude in the comments, but you probably didn't get my question either (even if some answers were part of mine below).
My assumption was that multiplicative modular inverses $\mod N$ were the same as the ones $\mod \phi(N)$ but it's clearly wrong. My assumption was to multiply by $e^{-1} \mod \phi(N)$, but the problem is that since the inverses of a number $\mod N$ and $\mod \phi(N)$ are different, this multiplication wouldn't 'produce' $a$.
i.e.
$ae^{-1}e \mod N \neq a$
if
$e$ and $e^{-1}$ are inverses $\mod \phi(N)$ and not $\mod N$
Also, if we proceed taking $e, e^{-1} \mod N$, as someone has already replied, would restrict the security of RSA to compute the EEA (Extendend Euclid Algorithm) which is way faster to compute compared to the factorization, hence breaking the security of the protocol.

On cryptography SE: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34938

You might find these algorithms interesting.

@Sil that link don't solve the problem since the answer is the same as the one here below. They say that it's easy to compute the inverse while it's not.

@J.G. you linked the Diffie-Hellman wiki page, definitely not helpful I'm sorry

I didn't say it was helpful, I said it might be interesting. Once you understand why RSA uses exponentiation rather than multiplication, you will know how to answer the analogous DH question.

@J.G. that is the question I wrote up here. If you assume you know the answer why don't you just write it here?

When I wrote my original comment, I didn't know you'd called to understand how the original answer addresses your question. Perhaps the most recent answer will help you more.

See the linked dupes for how and why RSA works, i.e. the (encryption) power map $a\mapsto a^e\bmod N,$ is a trapdoor function, i.e. modular $e$'th powers can be computed quickly, but decrypting = inverting = taking $e$'th roots is hard. But an $e$-scaling map $,a\mapsto e\cdot a\bmod N,$ is easy to invert: the inverse map is $,a\mapsto e^{-1}a\bmod N,$ where $e^{-1}\bmod N$ can be quickly computed, e.g. by ext. euclidean algorithm. $\  \ $

Finding the modular inverse is easy, using the Extended Euclidean algorithm.  That is, you  solve
$ax + N y = 1$, where $a$ and $N$ are coprime, and then $a^{-1} \equiv x \mod N$.

You literally wrote that breaking RSA is easy.

@zhyn: No, the modular inverse (easy) is not the same as the inverse logarithm (hard).

@TonyK if we manage to find the inverse of $d$, aka $d^{-1} = e$ we can decrypt messages, what's wrong with you guys ahah.

@zhyn you know the modulus $pq$. The "inverse of $e$" that you need is modulo $\phi(pq)$, which is hard to find if you don't know the factors $p$ and $q$.

@zhyn I'm sure you have it all fully understood and a bunch of 5-figure rep mathematics here are the ones who are confused...

@2'59'2 give a complete answer

@zhyn I'm afraid your question can't be directly answered. It starts out "If the problem of RSA is X .." and that's just not the problem of RSA. Your question opens with a false premise so it's impossible to answer directly. I tried in my answer to help you see this. Good luck, and you'll understand it at some point. Maybe take a break from it for a bit.

You have a misunderstanding of RSA. In this subject there is arithmetic mod $N$, and to do that you need an inverse mod $\varphi(N)$. Finding that inverse is easy as in @RobertIsrael's answer. But finding what $\varphi(N)$ is without knowing the factorization of $N$ is the hard part.

The inverse of $e$ is $d$, hence the inverse of $d$ is $e$

Or $\lambda(N)$, as the case may be.

$N$ is publicly known. But $\varphi(N)$ is not. That makes finding an inverse mod $\varphi(N)$ hard, to put it mildly. You seem to be thinking about finding an inverse mod $N$ though, and that misunderstanding is leading to this question you have asked.
